# No such file errors when compiling "Hello, world!" wx-widgets app on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, clang, wxwidgets

I have installed wx-widgets on my Mac (macOS Big Sur) via Homebrew

```
brew install wxwidgets
```

But when I try to compile [this](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_helloworld.html) or [this](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Hello_World) Hello, World! example I get and errors

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'libexpat.tbd'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'libz.tbd'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'libiconv.tbd'
```

I use this command from [wx-config documentation](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Wx-Config):

```
g++ `wx-config --cxxflags` -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp `wx-config --libs`
```

Just what I am doing wrong?

`wx-config --cflags` output:

`-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-static-3.1 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.1 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXOSX_COCOA__ -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -pthread`

`wx-config --libs` output:

````
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread /usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_qa-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_html-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.a -lwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1 -lwxjpeg-3.1 -lwxpng-3.1 -lwxtiff-3.1 -framework AudioToolbox -framework WebKit -lwx_baseu-3.1 libexpat.tbd libz.tbd -lwxregexu-3.1 libiconv.tbd -framework CoreFoundation -framework Security -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework QuartzCore```
````

Comment: Can you edit your post with the output produced by `wx-config --cflags` and `wx-config --libs`?

Comment: @Vulpes-Vulpeos, why not build the library yourself?

Comment: @Botje, done, outputs are in the post.

Comment: @Igor, because it's easier and faster to just download it via brew.
But I'll do it if it solve this errors.

Comment: @Vulpes-Vulpeos, it should. Most like ly the cause of the errors is that your OSX doesn't have those libraries installed. It is much faster and easier to just build everything yourself then rely on someone to do everything for you. ;-)

Comment: `wx-config --libs` output seems wrong to me, it shouldn't contain these `libexpat.tbd` etc parts, I think. Do you have these files at all (you could use Spotlight to search for them)? Perhaps they're provided by Homebrew in some non-default directory? If not, this looks like a packaging bug that should be reported.

Comment: @Igor, you were right. I built wxwidgets myself and now apps compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by [building](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.3/plat_osx_install.html)  wxwidgets from source.
The command to build apps also need to be changed to

```
g++ `full/path/to/wx-config ` -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp `full/path/to/wx-config --libs`
```

or

```
g++ -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp `full/path/to/wx-config --libs --cxxflags`
```